# Magento V1.7 Grid View - Add manufacturer attribute to view

Tags: magento

On [this page](http://www.foxtrotgear.com/index.php/tactical-gear-equipment.html?mode=grid) I want to add the Manufacturer name directly below the name of the item, but can't seem to get this to work.  Have tried a number of suggestions, but none seem to work.

Please be specific on the file and lines to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming that you are using attribute set  to create a 'manufacturer' field in Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Attributes.

Write a custom module that extend Catalog Product Block Grid
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

Create Block File: app/code/local/MageIgniter/ManufacturerGrid/Block/AdminhtmlCatalog/Product/Grid.php

```
class MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
 {
```

Copy method _prepareCollection() to you custom block and update (line 58)

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')   // added this line
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

Copy method _prepareColumns() to you custom block and add

```
    $this->addColumn('manufacturer',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manufacturer'),
            'width' => '60px',
            'index' => 'manufacturer',
            'type'  => 'options';
            'options' => Mage::helper('manufacturergrid')->getManufacturerOption(),
    ));
```

Create Helper File: app/code/local/MageIgniter/ManufacturerGrid/Helper/Data.php

```
 class MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
 {

    public function getManufacturerOption(){
       $_opt = array();
       foreach (Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','manufacturer')->getSource()->getAllOptions(false,true) as $option){
           $_opt[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
       }

    return $_opt;
   }  

 }
```

Create: app/code/local/MageIgniter/ManufacturerGrid/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid>    
  </modules>

  <global>
      <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
            <catalog_product_grid>MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
      </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <localship>
            <class>MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid_Helper</class>
        </localship>
    </helpers>
  </global>
 </config>
```

Create: app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
           <modules>
                  <MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid>
                          <active>true</active>
                          <codePool>local</codePool>
                  </MageIgniter_ManufacturerGrid>
           </modules>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$manufacturer_items = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')->getCollection()->setStoreFilter()
    ->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code');

    foreach ($manufacturer_items as $manufacturer_item) :
        if ($manufacturer_item->getAttributeCode() == 'manufacturer')
        $manufacturer_options[$manufacturer_item->getOptionId()] = $manufacturer_item->getValue();
    endforeach;

    $this->addColumn('manufacturer',
        array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manufacturer'),
        'width' => '100px',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'index' => 'manufacturer',
        'options' => $manufacturer_options,
        ));
```

Put this code in Gird.php file and this code in apoximate line number 58 to 63 in same file 
->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')