# Need URL rewrite for brand listing

Tags: magento

I want to make URL for SEO optimization.

```
My URL is: supplements.html?manufacturer=166
I want URL like: supplements/manufacturer/scivation.html
```

(scivation is manufacturerfor id 166 and supplementsis category and manufacturer is attribute)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this only using magento or magento/apache mod_rewrite?

Comment: hi RS.i would prefer to do it using magento.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'supplements' is a category (which changes) it's going to be more difficult to use a writing rule without hard coding. One possible solution is to use `Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154521/gernerate-custom-urls-within-magento)) to create a route for each (you may run into issues using this method)

Another solution would be to change the url format

> /manufacturer/supplements/scivation.html

Then create a custom module

config.xml

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
      <fancy_url>
            <from><![CDATA[/manufacturer\/(.*)/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[manufacturer/index/processroute/manufacturername/$2/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
       </fancy_url>
    <rewrite>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <tagseo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <frontName>customcategory</frontName>
            </args>
        </tagseo>
    </routers>

class MageIgniter_Manufacturer_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
     public function processRoute(){
           print_r($requestUri = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri()); //supplements/scivation.html
           print_r($this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturername')); // scivation.html
           print_r($this->getRequest())
           // do you custom logic here base on about request path explode('/', trim($requestUri,'/'))

           //lookup the attribute_id from attribute name 
           //if attribute_id found then try 
           //$this->_forward(string $action, [string|null $controller = null], [string|null $module = null], [ $params = null])
           // to the catalog page
           // else  $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');


     }
     ...
```

Read more @

[Simple URL Rewrite Using Magento xml](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml)

[Magento Router Url - Need Hyphnated Path Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238428/magento-router-url-need-hyphnated-path-name)

[Magento V1.7 Grid View - Add manufacturer attribute to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699980/magento-v1-7-grid-view-add-manufacturer-attribute-to-view)